# Identify this dead cactus - like a cleistocactus strausii, but super-dwarf?

Tags: identification, houseplants, cactus

Can anybody identify this cactus?

It appears to me to be something between *[mammillaria elongata](https://www.rhs.org.uk/Plants/10815/i-Mammillaria-elongata-i/Details)* and *[cleistocactus strausii](https://www.rhs.org.uk/plants/details?plantid=2459)* - but small, each column at most a long finger, and narrower.

[image: unknown cactus]

It died some time ago, which obviously doesn't help in identifying it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mammillaria elongata, your first guess was spot on! Other than being dead, it looks ok...

Comment: Is it really? I was prepared for some colour change due to liveliness, but [this much greener (living) one](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Mammillaria-elongata-medium-size-plant/dp/B009HN3EJU) also seems less spiky, and more rounded?

Comment: M. elongata is pretty variable for stem diameter, spine color, spine coverage, etc. Flowers are all pretty much the same.

Comment: M. elongata is pretty variable for stem diameter, spine color, spine coverage, etc. Flowers are all pretty much the same. Spines are always recurved towards the body and it offsets readily. They don't get very tall, in habitat they grow in large mats on the ground. Your pictured plant looks to be pretty dried out which will affect how it looks. The link to the live plant is a young plant with fairly fat stems. They are SUPER common in big box stores here in SW USA. Better luck with your next one!

Comment: Thanks for your help! I'm looking to replace it as a gift, it's the colour that's particularly desirable, so the variability isn't at all helpful!